# Using tkinter to select and save a file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am looking to create a reminder that prompts the user to select a file if they've completed it.  After selecting the file they want, I would like the script to save that file to a specific folder.  This is what I have so far...

```
import tkinter
import time
import win32api
from tkinter import messagebox

dialog_title = 'Complaince calendar'
dialog_text = 'Have you completed the monthly spreadsheet?'
answer = messagebox.askquestion(dialog_title, dialog_text)

if answer == 'yes':
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import filedialog

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

else:  # 'no'
    win32api.MessageBox(0, 'Make sure you get that done', 'Compliance calendar')
```

How can I save the file_path to a specified folder?

Thanks!!

Comment: You're asking how to write to a file? Have you read any python tutorials? This is a pretty basic question with many, many examples on the internet.

Comment: [shutil.copyfile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) ?

Comment: shutil.copy worked! thank you